# Remove file extension successfully but not sub directory

Tags: php, .htaccess

First of all, I have created .htaccess on the root folder.

The code would be like this

```
RewriteEngine on

# Rewrite /foo/bar to /foo/bar.php
RewriteRule ^([^.?]+)$ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L]

# Return 404 if original request is /foo/bar.php
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$"
RewriteRule .* - [L,R=404]

# NOTE! FOR APACHE ON WINDOWS: Add [NC] to RewriteCond like this:
# RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} "^[^ ]* .*?\.php[? ].*$" [NC]
```

The result is like this **localhost/domain/index.php** become **localhost/domain/index**. It is success.

But the problem is I would like to navigate to **subdir** named *demo* after **index**. It would be like this **localhost/domain/index/demo/firstfolder/index**.

When I try that, it is written "**The requested URL /domain/demo/firstfolder/.php was not found on this server.**".

What am I missing?

What I want is like this below.

**localhost/domain/demo/firstfolder/.php** become **localhost/domain/index/demo/subsubfolder**.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better not to use `%{REQUEST_URI}.php` since `%{REQUEST_URI}` can have trailing slash.

Have your rules likes this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /domain/

# Return 404 if original request is /foo/bar.php 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.php 
RewriteRule ^ - [L,R=404]

# Rewrite /domain/bar to /domain/bar.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: I see, but i have tried to use yours but seems it doesn't work. It won't work for localhost/domain/index. What should I do? @anubhava

Comment: It does work for me and rewrites it to `localhost/domain/index.php`. Make sure you have ONLY this code and nothing else in DocumentRoot/.htaccess aldo make sure you are able to open: `localhost/domain/index.php` (by commenting 404 rule for testing)

Comment: Weird, why mine doesn't work. Only .htaccess in my root folder. Nothing else. @anubhava

Comment: First of all try putting efforts in answering my comments. `Doesn't work` is pretty much useless unless you provide some details. Did you do as I suggested above i.e. commenting out 404 rule and opening `localhost/domain/index.php` URL?

Comment: Yes, I have been trying that all the time. Anyway, I used your code and put in the root folder. It is showing that **The requested URL /domain/index was not found on this server.**. Actually the code I inserted above was working very well.

Comment: Did you do second testing part as I suggested?

Comment: I did, I just put .htaccess in my root folder. Isnt that you mean? @anubhava

Comment: First try opening this URL `localhost/domain/index.php` and tell me what you get. Then comment out first 404 rule in my answer and then try loading same URL and tell me what you get.

Comment: Hello, I tried to open `localhost/domain/index.php` using your answer and what i get is **The requested URL /anthonywebdeveloper/index was not found on this server.**. And what do you mean comment out first 404 rule in your answer? Like what?

Comment: Why it is so difficult to understand? There are 2 rules in my answer and I have repeated myself 3 times to comment it out. I am making a change in my answer to take out that part now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59856/discussion-between-anthosiast-and-anubhava).